# Angular 7 Trying to make 2 http get requests in same *ngFor

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to make 2 GET requests and use it in `*ngFor`, any solution or docs to resolve it?
i already made an service api to GET,POST,UPDATE and REMOVE
Using a service i am invoking these methods on my REST service.

and i just push the link from this component service (SuperheroService )

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SuperheroService {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }
  get() {
    return this.apiService.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  }
  getImgHero(){
    return this.apiService.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
  }
```

SuperheroComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SuperheroService } from './superhero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-superhero',
  templateUrl: './superhero.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./superhero.component.css']
})
export class SuperheroComponent implements OnInit {
heros: any[] = [];
herosImg: any[]= [];
  constructor(private superheroService: SuperheroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.superheroService.get().subscribe(resp => {
      this.heros = resp;
    });
    this.superheroService.getImgHero().subscribe(Response=>{
    this.herosImg = Response;
    // console.log(Response);

    });
    // this.superheroService.get().subscribe(([res1, res2])=> {
    // this.heros = [res1, res2];
    // });
  }


}
```

and the html code that has data-binding is as below:

```
*ngFor="let hero of heros | slice:0:5; let isFirst = first"  [class.active]="isFirst">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Comment: Please provide much more detail, at least a portion of the template that is failing and the code inside component that is making the api call. It is not possible to expect someone to help you with so little information.

Comment: A template (or a component) shouldn't be making *any* HTTP calls, so it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you want a forkJoin

```
ngOnInit() {
    forkJoin(this.superheroService.get(),
             this.superheroService.getImgHero())
             .subscribe(res)=> {
                //in res[0] you has "heros" and in res[1] you has herosImg
                //I supouse you want to "join"
                //Imagine that hero has "id" and other properties
                //        and heroImg has "id" and "src"
                this.heros = res[0].map(hero=>{
                    let heroImg=res[1].find(heroImg=>heroImg.id==hero.id);
                    return { 
                       ...hero;
                       img:heroImg?heroImg.src:null;
                    })
                })
    });
  }
```